# How to not Load Image in Hidden Sidebar

Tags: html, css, joomla

I use CSS to hide the right-hand Sidebar on Mobile Devices

Example: https://www.guru99.com/best-bitcoin-mining-software.html

But the images still end-up loading and add to page speed times

Example: https://www.guru99.com/images/2/kryptex-300x250.gif

Is there any way not to load the sidebar images, js altogether on Mobile Device?

Comment: you can check your window size with `window.innerWidth` and if it's less that what you have in mind, you can remove `src` of your images to prevent them from loading with `document.getElementById('img').removeAttribute('src')`

Answer (score 0):

The reason it still loads is because the `img` element was introduced before `css` was brought into picture.

Just add `loading="lazy"` to your `img` tag and it would work in all browsers that support `loading` attribute.

Adding `loading="lazy"` works because it will load image only if its brought in viewport by scrolling or changing the styles

See the demo here.

https://codeframe.co/f/80f3d7f547ad/e3b0c44298fc.html

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the `<picture>` element to stop data wastage.

```
  <picture>
    <source srcset="data:image/gif;base64,QKGDODNVJD/AAAAAAAAAAAADDDSs=" media="(max-width: 768px)"> 
    <img src="logo.png" alt="imgage" width="512" height="512">
  </picture>
```

When the viewport width becomes smaller than 768px the browser will switch to the alternative source, a dummy base64 image(cost less than a Kb).

- Now, you can use CSS to remove `<img>` from the page layout.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
      img{
        display: none;
      }
    }
```

Read more about [picture element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)